# passing structure array to function

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I've been learning C for about 2 months, still a novice:(

I know there are other similar questions on this site. I've read them, but still couldn't really understand, so here I am. Below is my code:

```
//naming my structure as ball
typedef struct ball_room {
int enter;
int exit;
} ball;

//I've omitted some irrelevant details for brevity
    int i, n, max;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    ball person[n];
    .../*assign values to ball.enter and ball.exit with user input*/
    max = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (ball_room(person, person[i].enter, n) > max)
            max = ball_room(person, person[i].enter, n);
    printf("%d\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

and below is my function receiving the array:

```
//This function returns the number of people in the ballroom
//when b[j](person[j] in "main") enters
int ball_room(ball *b, int i, int n)
{
    int people = 0, j;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if (b[j].enter <= i && b[j].exit > i)
            people++;
    return people;
}
```

my question is that why is it `b[j].enter` instead of `b[j]->enter`, which my compiler wouldn't accept?
In my limited experience, when manipulating structure itself (the object), I use `.` to go inside the structure, and when it's a pointer (the address), I use `->` (hope this is correct.)

And in this case, I pass the array to function using `ball *b`, which represent  the address of `person[0]`, so I can access the whole array. But shouldn't `ball *b` be in the form of a pointer and therefore I should use `->` to access its content? It's just an address that I pass to the function.

This is my first time doing something with an array of structures, please help me get this clear, thank you!

Comment: If you understand, its interesting to know that `->` is a convenient way for expressing value at <object>.<member>, in yours case `(*b).enter`, `enter` is a member in the said struct with having `b` as a pointer to `struct ball_room` type.

Comment: Also, avoid using `ball_room` for function and for `struct ball_room` at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given `ball *b`, `b[j]` is an element from the elements that `b` points to. Thus `b[j]` is not a pointer; it is a struct. Since it is a struct, you use `.` to refer to members in it.

The definition of `b[j]` in the C standard is that it is `*((b)+(j))`. So it takes the pointer `b`, moves `j` elements beyond it, and then applies `*`.

Since `*` is already applied in `b[j]`, you do not need `->`, just `.`.

Answer (score 5):

you use `.` instead of `->` because of this declaration of parameters:

`int ball_room(ball *b, int i, int n)`

`b` is expected to be pointer to data with type `ball`, so you can access it in various ways:

1. array way: e.g. `b[5].somefield = 15` - you use dot here, because if `b` is of type `ball *`, it means that `b` is pointer OR it is array of objects with type `b`, if it's array of objects with type `b` (which is your case) you use `.` to access fields of object
2. pointer way: e.g. `(b+5)->somefield = 15` - it will do exactly same thing as code above, but you will access data in `pointer` way

Comment: To be more precise: b is *always* a pointer - it can *point* to either a single object or an array (if it *were* an array, it wouldn't be necessary any more provide array size in separate parameters...).

Comment: To be even more precise, it is always a pointer that points to a single object. As a convention with arrays this single object would be the first element of an array.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Correct in detail, but as both the array and its first element share the same address (`&a[0]` and `&a` yield the same value, but pointer *type* differs), I consider it OK to say "points to the array". This is where C is just much more precise than spoken language (see differing pointer type...).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala -- to belabor the point, the single object _might_ be an array, e.g. `char arr[][5] = { "test", "test" }; char (*p_row)[5] = arr;` after which `sizeof *p_row;` yields a value of 5 since `p_row` points the the first element of the array, which happens to be an array of 5 `char`s.

Comment: Actually, any single element can be considered as array of size 1; even the one-past-end pointer is valid for single elements, so you can do: `int c = 7, d; my_special_memcpy(&d, &c, &c+1);`...

Comment: @Aconcagua -- it is valid to form the address one past the end of an array using pointer arithmetic, and objects that are not array elements behave as arrays of one element _for the purposes of pointer arithmetic_, but it is still UB to attempt to access an object one past the end of that array.

Comment: @DavidBowling Assumed this was already clear by the term OPEP?

Comment: @DavidBowling Ah, my fault - someone *not familiar with* might have got the bad idea from, so thanks for being explicit...

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ an array devolves into the address of it's first member. So when you pass the array to `ball_room` what actually gets passed is `&ball[0]`.

Now inside `ball_room` the reverse happens. `b` is a pointer to ball. But here you use it as an array `b[j]`. So it un-devolves back into an array of structs. So what `b[j]` gives you is the struct and not a pointer to a struct. Consequently you access it using `.` instead of `->`.

You can also use `(b + j)->somefield`. Or for even more fun how about writing `j[b].somefield`. The later being a really confusing left-over from the eraly compiler days when `a[b]` truly got turned into `*(a + b)` internally.

Comment: *"So it un-devolves back into an array of structs"*. No. The pointer remains a pointer. Using the index operator does not change *anything* on this. `x[y]` is just short for `*(x + y)` (that part nicely explained). If doing so on arrays, the array actually decays already to a pointer! To make it more obvious: `x[7]` is equivalent to `*(x + 7)`, and as commutative, as well to `*(7 + x)`. Using short variant again, you get `7[x]` -- which, big surprise, is absolutely valid and working code...

Comment: @Aconcagua which is already mentioned in my answer. No need to repeat it as comment.

Comment: The cited sentence is technically plain wrong! If the pointer "un-devolved back into an array", you could apply `sizeof`` on that array again, so passing to functions lengths together with arrays would get obsolete...

Comment: How else do you say the compiler takes it as if it where an array. Blame C for the mess of making arrays equal to pointers except not always. My answer is written so layperson can understand it, not  define a new c standard.

Comment: See Eric's answer (which, for now, is the only one I upvoted). Your wording is dangerous especially for beginners, which might guide them to doing things like `void f(char* b) { size_t n = sizeof(b); }` and thinking they get the size of the array back...

Answer (score 2):

For explanation of the current issue, see [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51264543/1312382); in some of the answers given so far there is dangerous wording applied, so just to make clear: When do we have an array and when a pointer???

Consider the following:

```
int a[7];
```

As long as we can refer to `a` directly, we still have an array and can use any operations that are valid on, e. g. getting size:

```
size_t n = sizeof(a); // size in bytes, not ints, i. e. 7*sizeof(int)
```

You can pass arrays to functions or even do pointer arithmetics on:

```
f(a);
a + 1;
```

In both cases, the array "decays" to a pointer, though, and the result is a pointer as well. Be aware that you can assign new values to a pointer, but not to an array itself (you can assign new values to the array's elements, directly or via pointer), so you cannot do things like `++a` either.

When an array decays to a pointer, it gets a pointer to its first element:

```
int* ptr = a;
int* ptr = &*a;    // only pointers can be dereferenced -> a decays!
int* ptr = &a[0];  // short for &*(a + 0)...
```

All result in exactly the same; however, the following is invalid:

```
int* ptr = &a;
```

Taking the address of an entire array actually *is* possible, but the resulting pointer is not of type "pointer to element" nor of type "pointer to pointer to element" (`int**` in the example), but of type "pointer to array of specific size". Syntax for is ugly, though, but the following would be legal again:

```
int(*aptr)[7] = &a;
```

You need to read: if I dereference `ptr`, I get `int[7]`...

Once decayed, there is only a pointer to the array left (more precisely: to one of the array elements, directly after decaying, to the first; array and first element always share the same address, so, although of different type, both pointers `ptr` and `aptr` from above hold exactly the same value). Pointers can be moved around within the array, but they do not hold as much information as the array itself, especially, the array size gets lost. This is why one needs to pass the array's length together with the pointer to functions (if needed; another variant is a sentinel value denoting the array end such as the terminating null character in strings or the null pointer following the string arguments in `main`'s arguments list):

```
int a[7];
f(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)); // division: sizeof is in bytes, dividing by size
                            // of first element gives number of elements
```

Possibly with f as:

```
void f(int b[], size_t n)
//     ^^^^^^^ in function parameter lists, just alternative syntax for int* b !!!
//             however, we can show more explicitly that we expect a pointer
//             to an array this way...   
{
    size_t m = sizeof(b); // as b is a POINTER, gives the constant (but hardware specific!)
                          // size of a pointer (on typical modern 64-bit hardware 8 bytes),
                          // no matter what size of the array being pointed to is!!!

    while(n)
    {
        *b++ = n--;
    //    ^^ advances pointer, NOT array!
    }
}
```

Hope this helps to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the array name is a pointer to array’s first element, hence your function declaration has name `ball *b`and works when you pass a `ball[]` instance.

Try dynamically allocating the memory by using `malloc()` and passing that pointer to your function.

Comment: Only if the array decayed to a pointer already, either because of assigning to a pointer variable or because of doing pointer arithmetics on; `int a[7]; size_t n = sizeof(a);` wouldn't work if `a` was already a pointer even here...